# iOS - app icon doesn't appear while app is loading

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using the asset catalog and all the images for the app icon are chosen with zero errors/warnings in the asset catalog.

When loading the app, the white app icon template (the one with lines that look like a target) appears behind the progress circle and it is grayed out. Only once the app finishes loading and installing then my desired app icon appears. Has anybody seen this and have a solution? I have tried almost everything I can think of:

1. Used all the standard app icon names and sizes and included in project
2. Add those app icons to the info.plist's cd bundleprimaryicon dictionary.

The above didn't work so tried asset catalog which also didn't solve the issue.

His occurs whether I distribute the app using either ad hoc or enterprise cert.

Running Xcode 6.1, iOS 8.1

Comment: Is `display-image` in your distribution manifest pointing valid image URL?

Comment: the distribution manifest doesn't apply to us, since we're not using over the air. we're just pushing via an .ipa through itunes

Answer (score 0):

You can add files like this:

project files added:

[image]
\n

- info.plist added:

[image]

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I have tried and it does not work which is why I am confused.

Comment: send a dome projects for me and check it what is wrong: MAIL: qqiang.dev@gmail.com. then i can send it back to you